# Troubles with testing delete value from object on different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, coffeescript, jasmine

I need to test deletion from a hash:

```
store = { 'a': 4 }
delete store['a']
expect(store['a']).toBeUndefined()
```

this test passed on chrome, but not in firefox. I get:

```
Expected null not to be defined.
```

How can I avoid this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the wrong condition so it doesn't matter if Chrome and Firefox are returning different values (but see below). Consider this:

```
store = { a: 11 }
store['a'] = undefined
```

That will give you a `store['a']` that is `undefined` but `store` will still have `'a'` as a key.

If you want to check if `delete` removes the property, say exactly that:

```
expect('a' of store).toBe(false)
```

CoffeeScript's `of` operator is JavaScript's `in` operator and from the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#Using_in_with_deleted_or_undefined_properties):

> **Using in with deleted or undefined properties**
>
> If you delete a property with the `delete` operator, the `in` operator returns false for that property.
>   [...]
>   If you set a property to `undefined` but do not delete it, the `in` operator returns `true` for that property.

That's exactly the behavior you're trying to test.

---

For the record, when I say:

```
store = { 'a': 4 }
delete store['a']
console.log store['a']
```

I get `undefined` in the latest Firefox.

Comment: firefox says that I'm using the latest version of firefox... This seems interesting

Comment: I get the same results from http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dm2scgf4/ everywhere, do you? If you do, can you replicate your problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?